# Доступ к ArrayList, заполняемому в цикле, за пределами этого цикла

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Voltage_array.length - 1; i++)
{
    if (Voltage_array[i] <= 0.7)
    {
        period = true;
    }
    if (Voltage_array[i] > 0.7 & period) 
    {
        ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        list.add(time_array[i]);
        period = false;
    }
}
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы доступ к динамическому массиву был за пределами цикла и чтобы он наполнялся значениями? Так как сейчас в него записывается одно значение, а потом идет перезапись.

Comment: Убедитесь, кстати, что вы действительно хотите использовать `&` а не `&&`. Проблема в том, что если постоянно использовать `&` там, где предполагается `&&`, то рано или поздно это выйдет боком.

Comment: Интересно, поменял на  `&&` ,  результат выполнения программы не поменялся. Хотите сказать, что в языке Java логическая операция AND выполняется через оператор  `&&` ?

Comment: Да, как и во многих других языках, в Java логическое `AND` - это `&&`. В то время как `&` - это побитовое `AND`. В случае использования двух `boolean` значений (например, `Voltage_array[i] > 0.7` и `period`) разницы в результатах нет. Однако даже в этом случае использовать оператор, смысл которого в другом, на мой взгляд, несколько неуместно.

Comment: Спасибо за ценную информацию.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы иметь доступ к переменной вне блока, нужно её объявить на том уровне, где мы хотим с ней работать или выше.

http://kulibaba.net/programming/java/lesson4

У вас каждый раз создаётся новый объект `list`. Соответственно, все значения, что в нём были, стираются. И на выходе получается только один элемент.

То есть достаточно создать список перед циклом.

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList <Double> ();
for (int i=0; i<=Voltage_array.length-1; i++){  
    if (Voltage_array[i] <= 0.7)        
        period = true;

    if (Voltage_array[i] > 0.7 & period){       
        list.add(time_array[i]);
        period = false;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное !!!

Answer (score 3):

Вынести строку `ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList <Double> ();` за пределы цикла(если, конечно, я правильно понял вопрос и доступ нужен именно к этому листу)

Comment: Спасибо Вам !!!